# In C, how do you know if the argument passed is a list or a pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

So I was working on Codewars and I got given
`void func(const struct struct_name  *name)`
to work with. So I wondered, in other general cases, how would I know if it's just a pointer to a particular structure or a pointer to an array of the structures?

In this particular case, I iterated over the given thing and it turned out to be an array

Comment: You cannot know for sure. How did you iterate it? When did you stop? If you were expecting '\n' or NULL, then this is very undefined behaviour. As a convention, when a function accepts a pointer, it is one object, when it accepts a pointer and a length parameter, then it's an array.

Comment: The only way, that API manual.

Comment: Read the documentation about how the function is called?

Comment: There is no "general case". You need to refer to the documentation or if there is none, you need to need to look at the calling code and/or ask the person who gave you whatever you're supposed to work with.

Comment: In case it's an array, there's also a size parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tell from that declaration if `name` points to a single object or to an element of an array.  Refer to documentation or existing code.

For arrays there are two widely used conventions:

1. Pass in length/size argument like `size_t n`. Since c99  you can declare [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) arguments with either fixed (static) size or a VLA:

   ```
   void func(const struct struct_name name[3]);
   void func(const struct struct_name name[static 3]);
   void func(size_t n, const struct struct_name name[n]);
   ```
2. Use a sentinel to indicate the last element.  strings, for instance, use '\0'.  If it's an array of pointers NULL is usually used.

Finally, some data structures use pointers between nodes with linked lists and trees probably being the most well known ones.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for a function declared like

```
void SomeFunction(SomeType *x);
```

there is no way to tell if a pointer to a single object or if a pointer to an array was passed to the function. However, if the function expects an array it should also take the length of the array as a separate parameter. Also, the name of the formal parameter should indicate that it stands for a collection of things by using a plural form. Using square brackets instead of an asterisk also helps to make it clear that it's an array, e.g.

```
void SomeFunction(SomeType items[], int intemsLen);
```

My own convention is to always append *Len* to the name of an array to denote its length. This minimizes the risk of mixing up different array lengths.

In some cases a sentinel can also be used to indicate the end of an array (instead of using a separate length variable), the most well known example being the string terminator '\0'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value